# Having trouble using python2.7 to access Active Directoy

Tags: python, python-2.7, active-directory

I tried using Auth0 from Windows, but its only a trial. The GUI application is suppose to have access to the local Active Directory Users and Computers. By use

Which I am trying to figure out the simplest way to implement.

Comment: I've used this link, its just unclear on the GUI design to link to the source code.
I am still a novice to python programming.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

```
import os

path = "your path"

# Check current working directory.

retval = os.getcwd()
print "Current working directory %s" % retval

# Now change the directory
os.chdir( path )

# Check current working directory.
retval = os.getcwd()

print "Directory changed successfully %s" % retval
```